# Strange Issue : Convert Single Line of Text To Multiple line of text

Tags: ootb

I am facing a very strange issue, there is a single line of text column in SharePoint List. I want to change it to Multiple Line of text, when I go to list settings and click on the column it does not give me options to change the Column, see the screenshot attached.

[image: This is the screen of what i see when i go to List settings then to this column]

I then tried to change it using the code, Below is my code.

`

```
                        SPField field = fields[columnName];

                        try
                        {
                            if (field != null)
                                Console.WriteLine("Field Type current :" + field.Type);
                            field.SchemaXml = field.SchemaXml.Replace("Text", "Note");
                            field.Update();
                            NewsLetter.Update();
                            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Message:" + ex.Message);                             
                        }

                    }`
```

I tried to run the code for my dev env and it worked the same code does not works for my prod env, where i need to make this changes.

Answer (score 1):

That is not good idea.
Create new column, then copy values from single line of text column to the created column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://aissp2013/sites/TestSite"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(""))
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["XYZ"];
        SPField field = list.Fields["ABC"];
        field.Type = SPFieldType.Note;
        field.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works on my Dev, Still no luck on my production environment :( Any more suggestions ?

Comment: Not sure about this, but can you see if you can update it using SharePoint Manager.

Comment: Tried using and Powershell no effect, will try using SP Manager